# Oil in coolant but no coolant in oil 2014 Ford Edge 3.5

Tags: ford, oil, coolant, edge

I just bought a 2014 Ford Edge 3.5L SE with 114,000 miles on it.  I noticed oil in the coolant tank.  I performed a very thorough coolant flush.  Still oil in coolant.  No coolant in the oil.  I read that it could be a leaking oil cooler. Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!